# PrintWriter to write to CSV - New line not working?

Tags: java, csv, printwriter

I've tried just about everything I could find online and on this particular site and none of these options are working. I'm looping through a list of objects and creating a CSV file. I'd like to break at each object entry, but no luck so far.

Here is what I have currently:

```
    String value = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
            getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("cityId");
    
    String seperator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    
    try {
        
        PortletResponse response1 = (PortletResponse)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
        HttpServletResponse resp = PortalUtil.getHttpServletResponse(response1);
        resp.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/csv");
        resp.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=myFile.csv");

       List<Person> people = ppApi.getPeopleByCityId(Long.parseLong(value));
        
       PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        
       for(Person pp : people) {
            
           out.print(pp.getFirstName() + ",");
           out.print(pp.getLastName() + ",");
           out.print(pp.getEmail() + ",");
           out.print(pp.getPhone() + "%%n");
           out.print("\r\n");
           out.print("\n\r");
           out.print("\n");
           out.print("\r");
           out.print("\\r\\n");
           out.print("\\n");
           out.print("\\n\\r");
           out.print(seperator);
           out.println('\n');
           out.println("%n");
           out.println("%%n");
        }
        
        //Close the output stream
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So none of those things are working. My output looks something like this:

> jeff,smith,jsmith@email.com,555-123-1234
> rick,smith,rsmith@email.com,123-123-1233

Should look like:

> jeff,smith,jsmith@email.com,555-123-1234
>
> rick,smith,rsmith@email.com,123-123-1233

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, do not invent a bicycle and use [`Java CSV`](http://www.csvreader.com/java_csv.php) library. It will eliminate all your problems.

Comment: @user2124871 everything you want. The main advantage is that it will automatically escape all CSV's special symbols and will create valid csv file.

Comment: Excellent - Let me look into this.

Comment: Well - it's working, however, having issues with the output to stream. But I think it might be the right direction